# Injecting touch events

Tags: ubuntu-touch, touchscreen

Sorry if I seem a little green to the Linux/Ubuntu world. Its because I am.

On Windows 10 there is a C API called "InjectTouchInput" where you can inject a touch event into the system and it is handled as if were a touch screen sending touch events.

Is there an API like this in Linux or Ubuntu?

I am not interested in shell scripts, I want to write a C/C++ program to mimic touch events.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject multi-touch (and other input) events into the X11 server using the [XTest](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xextproto/xtest.html) extension.

You can inject various input events into the kernel using the [evdev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev) interface.

Neither is pretty and closer to a hardware than to an OS-level API.